# jQuery and noConflict when building classes, free the dollar sign for use inside declared methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the no conflict method to avoid conflicts between jQuery and Mootools.

```
$.noConflict();
```

When I define the following class, I use the "$" sing like in the following code, to free it up:

```
$.noConflict();

var Test = function ($) {

    this.method1 = function() {

        $('.testDiv').html('hey baby!');
    }

    this.method2 = function() {

        $('.testDiv').html('hey baby baby!');

    }
}
```

**Why doesn't it work?**

**Why do I have to use the $ sign for each method inside the class?**

Like this:

```
var Test = function () {

    this.method1 = function($) {

        $('.testDiv').html('hey baby!');
    }

    this.method2 = function($) {

        $('.testDiv').html('hey baby baby!');

    }
}
```

Comment: In the first example, how to you call the `Test()` function.  Are you passing it jQuery?

Comment: I do it like this var test = new Test(); -- and then test.method1() or test.method2()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, the problem is that you aren't passing the required argument when called the `Test()` constructor.

You said in your comment that you are doing:

```
var test = new Test();
```

That means that the first argument in the `Test` function will be undefined and thus `$` will be undefined.

You would need to do this instead:

```
var test = new Test(jQuery);
```

If you do that, the the argument definition of `$` will work for both your methods in your first code block.

Answer (score 0):

write in this way..

```
jq = $.noConflict(true);

and instead of using $ use jq like:
var Test = function (jq) {

    this.method1 = function() {

        jq('.testDiv').html('hey baby!');
    }

    this.method2 = function() {

        jq('.testDiv').html('hey baby baby!');

    }
}
```